# Can we make tag “Philosophy of English Language”?

Tags: discussion, tag-request

I think discussing language without philosophy is meaningless. What’s your opinion?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what such questions might be about?

Comment: @mdewey Subjectivity of English words. “How far can we describe something as “it’s tall” or “it’s short”?”

Comment: That question is far too open-ended and would be closed as "*opinion-based*".

Comment: @gotube You know it’s just a preview.

Comment: @user09827 I'm unclear what you mean by "preview". Regardless, there won't be general agreement on creating a new tag unless you can provide a list of clearly on-topic example questions for it, or even better, a handful of *existing* questions that would be improved if they had the tag.

Comment: @gotube Okay, I’ll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of ELL is not to "discuss language". We answer questions about English. Not just any questions though—[practical, answerable questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Philosophical questions are inherently unanswerable (in Stack Exchange terms), and are unsuitable for this format.

If you want to discuss philosophical questions, that belongs in one of the chat rooms, not on the Q&A pages.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this would add very much over and above the existing tag [semantics](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics) on the main site which currently has 50 questions. Admittedly that tag does not have a wiki yet suggesting it is not a very clear tag either.

Comment: Though, I wonder why some people ignore questions by saying “it’s a question about philosophy!” even though the posts are tagged “semantics”

Comment: Actually, there's an answer to that. Most users ignore the tags, which are arbitrary and useless. They might work for stack overflow and C++, but not in learning English.